# Plotly figure hide and display

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a problem with hiding and showing a graph in the Python framework, Dash.
I define a new graph:

```
html.Div([
  dcc.Graph(id = 'graph'),
 ],),
```

After I update my trace data with a callback function I return it and it is shown in the graph, but if nothing is selected from my dropdown menu I do

```
if not input or input == []:
  return {'display': 'none'}
```

so that my graph is not shown, but it doesn't work for some reason. 
Is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10):

You can set the `id` element for the Div holding your graph and hide the whole div by using `@app.callback` on the `style` element.

```
html.Div(id="graph-container", children= [
  dcc.Graph(id = 'graph'),
 ]),

@app.callback(Output('graph-container', 'style'), [Input('input_widget','value')])
def hide_graph(input):
    if input:
        return {'display':'block'}
    else:
        return {'display':'none'}
```

To see this code in action you can test out my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    html.Label("Show?"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="my-input",
        options = [
            {'label':'Yes', 'value':True},
            {'label':'No', 'value':False}
        ],
        value = True
    ),
    html.Div(
        id="graph-container", 
        children = [

        dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
    ])


])

@app.callback(Output('graph-container', 'style'), [Input('my-input', 'value')])
def hide_graph(my_input):
    if my_input:
        return {'display':'block'}
    return {'display':'none'}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8125, debug = True)
```

Note I used the following versions:

- python 3.6.4
- dash 0.21.0
- dcc 0.22.1
- html 0.10.0

Comment: Great answer. One addition: I found that I had to add a height attribute to the dcc.Graph object, otherwise my plot was only 1 pixel tall. Like so: `style={'height': 400},`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks lwileczek for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862285).  I wanted to provide an update as the code needs a few minor tweaks to work in the following environment:

- python 3.7.4
- plotly 4.1.1
- dash 1.2.0
- dcc 1.1.2
- html 1.0.1

When I copied lwileczek's code into the above environment, dash through an error about passing a bad argument into the dropdown.  After a couple of moments of trial and error, I was able to make the code work if I changed the values in the dropdown to strings and modified the conditional in the callback so that it was doing a string comparison as opposed to expecting the value to be a boolean.

The code for the dropdown looks like:

```
dcc.Dropdown( 
    id = 'my-input', 
    options = [
        {'label':'Yes', 'value':'Yes'}, 
        {'label':'No', 'value':'No'}
    ], 
    value='Yes'
),
```

The code for the conditional in the callback becomes:

```
if my_input == 'Yes':
    return {'display': 'block'}
return {'display': 'none'}
```

(This should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough points to post a comment)